# vue.js firing $emit not received by $on

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

```js
Vue.component('rating-edit', {
    template:`
    <form>
      <input v-model="rating.title" type="text">
      <textarea v-model="rating.remark">{{rating.remark}}</textarea>
      <button type="button"
        @click="submit">
        Save
      </button>
    </form>`,
    props:['rating'],
    methods: {
      submit: function submit () {
        let rating = this.rating;
        this.$emit('submit', rating);
        console.log('submit was emitted');
      }
    }
  });

const aRating = {
    title: 'title',
    remark: 'remark'
  };

let vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#rating-edit-container',
    data: {
      rating: aRating
    }
  });

vueApp.$on('submit', function(rating) {
  console.log('vue on submit', rating);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating-edit-container">
  <rating-edit :rating="rating"></rating-edit>
</div>
```

In a legacy frontend code I'd like implement a vue based componentized form and have it return the data on submit.

This is the component code. Please note the submit function firing `this.$emit('submit', rating);`

```
let result = {
  props:['rating'],
  methods: {
    submit: function submit () {
      let rating = this.rating;
      this.$emit('submit', rating);
      console.log('submit fired');
    }
  }
};

export default result;
```

And now in the legacy code, I am waiting for the events:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ratingEditVue from './rating-edit.vue';


Vue.component('rating-edit', ratingEditVue);

const aRating = {
  title: 'title',
  remark: 'remark'
};

let vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#rating-edit-container',
  data: {
    rating: aRating
  }
});

vueApp.$on('submit', function(rating) {
  console.log('vue on submit', rating);
});
```

As far as I understand the Vue events this should work. But $on('submit', handlerFunction) just never gets called.

**Addendum:**

I've fiddled the example. I apologize for not having done this in the first place.

Comment: Can you provide any complete fiddle for your case?

Comment: You are `$emit`ing in a child component and setting up `$on` to catch events in the parent. `$on` catches events emitted in the current Vue (think of an event bus), so have the parent set it up on the child.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that you are emitting along the same scope depth of your `rating-edit` component.

If you instead emit to the parent with `this.$parent.$emit`, the event will be received by the parent.  Note, if you need to do this in multiple places or at multiple depths, you want to use an event bus instead.

```js
Vue.component('rating-edit', {
    template:`
    <form>
      <input v-model="rating.title" type="text">
      <textarea v-model="rating.remark">{{rating.remark}}</textarea>
      <button type="button"
        @click="submit">
        Save
      </button>
    </form>`,
    props:['rating'],
    methods: {
      submit: function submit () {
        let rating = this.rating;
        this.$parent.$emit('submit', rating);
        console.log('submit was emitted');
      }
    }
  });

const aRating = {
    title: 'title',
    remark: 'remark'
  };

let vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#rating-edit-container',
    data: {
      rating: aRating
    }
  });

vueApp.$on('submit', function(rating) {
  console.log('vue on submit', rating);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating-edit-container">
  <rating-edit :rating="rating"></rating-edit>
</div>
```

Comment: What??? I'd never have thought, that the $parent scope needs do be addressed. Never. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @LongHike Happy to help!  It's a slightly strange behavior, especially if you've worked with AngularJS or Vue 1.x events, but the event will not bubble like you might think, which is why this is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```js
vueApp.$on('submit', function(rating) {
  console.log('vue on submit', rating);
});
```

Your handler here will only be executed in response to `submit` events emitted from `vueApp` directly (i.e. `vueApp.$emit('submit')`), which I don't think is happening in your code (which isn't fully provided).

Vue events do not bubble.

Suppose your `#rating-edit-container` template is something like this:

```html
<template id="rating-edit-container">
  <div>
    <rating-edit @submit="onRatingSubmit"></rating-edit>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you should have your handler (`onRatingSubmit`) declared in the methods of your component like this:

```js
let vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#rating-edit-container',
  methods: {
    onRatingSubmit(rating) {
      console.log('rating submit', rating);
    },
  },
});
```

### EDIT

You still have the same issue as what I described. I modified your snippet by removing the emission on `$parent` instead of `this` and registering the listener on the `<rating-edit>` element in the template.

```js
Vue.component('rating-edit', {
    template:`
    <form>
      <input v-model="rating.title" type="text">
      <textarea v-model="rating.remark">{{rating.remark}}</textarea>
      <button type="button"
        @click="submit">
        Save
      </button>
    </form>`,
    props:['rating'],
    methods: {
      submit: function submit () {
        let rating = this.rating;
        this.$emit('submit', rating);
        console.log('submit was emitted');
      }
    }
  });

const aRating = {
    title: 'title',
    remark: 'remark'
  };

let vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#rating-edit-container',
    data: {
      rating: aRating
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit(rating) {
        console.log('vue on submit', rating);
      },
    },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="rating-edit-container">
  <rating-edit :rating="rating" @submit="onSubmit"></rating-edit>
</div>
```

Comment: Here, you could use `@submit.native="onRatingSubmit"` to handle the native submit event.

Comment: But no native event is being emitted, or is it? The native submit event is typically for forms.

Comment: It's not explicitly stated, but the user seems to want to intercept the native `submit` event from a form: "I'd like implement a vue based componentized form"

Comment: But they stated the event was being emitted via `this.$emit('submit', rating)` which is not a native event.

Comment: It's not that my submit is not being emitted. The $emit is taking place. I'am console-logging that.

It's that $on('submit') is not being called, although $on and $emit are on the same vue app instance.

I'll see if I can fiddle that.

Comment: @LongHike That's really weird. How could the `$on('submit')` line of code not be executed but the prior `let vueApp = new Vue` code be executed?

Comment: I've boiled down the example to a fiddle.